# ABP FindByNameOrEmailAsync method return null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

When I call the FindByNameOrEmailAsync method from postman it returns the user. But once I send the values through UI, the method returns null.
Though the value is bound to the usernameOrEmailAddress variable and come to the method, it returns null.

Can someone help me?

```
   <input type="email" id="emailInput" class="form-control" maxlength="255" placeholder="Enter your email" required />
   <button id="requestResetEmail" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Request password reset</button>


      abp.ui.setBusy(
        $('#LoginArea'),
        abp.ajax({
            url: abp.appPath + 'Account/ForgotPassword',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                usernameOrEmailAddress: $('#emailInput').val(),
                returnUrl: window.location.hash
            })
        })

  public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await 
          _userManager.FindByNameOrEmailAsync(model.UsernameOrEmailAddress);

        if (user == null || !(await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
            {                 
                return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
            }
        }
        else
        {
          return View(model);
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the correct tenant.

If the username or email address is unique across tenants, inject `IUnitOfWorkManager` and do:

```
using (_unitOfWorkManager.Current.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.MayHaveTenant))
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameOrEmailAsync(model.UsernameOrEmailAddress);
    // ...
}
```

If `_unitOfWorkManager.Current` is `null`, wrap the above code in:

```
using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
{
    // Above code goes here

    uow.Complete();
}
```

Comment: It gives this error 'CurrentUnitOfWork' does not exist in the current context. 
CurrentUnitOfWork have been used in the service layer and works fine. This .cs class is in the web project which implements login. And I am supposed to implement reset password functionality. Could you please tell me what should be done to CurrentUnitOfWork identifiable in the class.

Comment: Inject `IUnitOfWorkManager` and use `_unitOfWorkManager.Current` instead.

Comment: _unitOfWorkManager returned a null value . therefore I add _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(); then called the          (_unitOfWorkManager.Current.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.MayHaveTenant))    now it returns the user.  Thank You very much

Comment: If you make your method `virtual`, do you still need to begin `UnitOfWork`?